# How to display fullCalendar default view from monday?

Tags: laravel-5, fullcalendar

I want to display the full calendar view from Monday till Sunday, by default it shows from Sunday till Saturday.

I am working on laravel 5.2.

Please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

In the controller, try to add the option

`$calendar = $calendar::setOptions(['firstDay' => 1,]);`

*Edit: typo in setOptions: 'firstDay' is part of many options, forgot to close the array...*

**final:** Kindly select the answer as correct.

You are lucky I understood your question. You make use of the https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar package to help you to generate the http://fullcalendar.io javascript module. I've struggled with the same. The reason: an avalanche of options.

Comment: I did some changes to my controller but the suggestion helped me to get the output as I wanted. Thanks @Dimitri Mostery.